Unable to resolve GoogleSignin library in react native
I am unable to resolve the GoogleSignin issue when I ran the code below getting an error

(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNGoogleSignin' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary. [Component Stack].

I am new to react native development as well as Firebase and trying to figure this out for almost a week.
import { GoogleSignin } from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";
import { firebaseConfig } from "../Firebase/firebase_config";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

// Initialize Google Sign-In
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: firebaseConfig.webClientId, // Firebase web client ID
});

export default function Index() {
  // Google Sign-In handler
  const handleGoogleSignIn = async () => {
    try {
      // Perform the Google sign-in
      const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.getTokens();

      // Retrieve the ID token from the user object
      const idToken = userInfo.idToken; // Access idToken from userInfo

      // Create a Google credential using the ID token
      const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);

      // Sign in with Firebase using the credential
      await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
      Alert.alert("Success", "Signed in with Google!");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Google sign-in error", error);
      Alert.alert("Error", "Failed to sign in with Google.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Sign in with Google" onPress={handleGoogleSignIn} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
  },
});```

